# Bash file execution failure

Tags: shell-script, arch-linux

For whatever reason with default bash setup on Arch Linux, `./script` isn't working but `bash script` is.

The file is definitely owned by me, and permissions are 755 with executable bit set.

I've never seen this issue. Why can't I execute via `./script`

Comment: Is the filesystem holding `script` mounted `noexec`?

Comment: @icarus OMG yes LMAO. I forgot I set /home to noexec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/home, the partition running the script is mounted `noexec`

Fixed!